# Configurations of Reactants in Second Order Nucleophilic Substitutions

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

The question asks me to draw the product for the reactions. However, I am stuck and do not understand how to draw the reactants with configurations correctly.

(a) (S)-2-Chloropentane and NaSH

I thought the reactant I drew was in S configuration. Also, I thought since it was a chirality center, inversion of configuration will occur. Can someone please explain this in detail?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to pinpoint you in the right direction through comments, but apparantly I failed. The bottom line is that the molecule you drew and the one in the textbook answer are **identical.** Here’s why:

[image]

In the top row, you can see the (*S*)-2-chloropentane, which I have drawn as you have on the left, slowly rotating around an axis equivalent to the reaction arrows to give you *the same molecule drawn in a different orientation.*

Now, if you do an $\mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{N}}2$ reaction, all you need to do is replace the chlorine atom and invert the stereochemistry which I have done for both cases. You can now see that both sides are identical.

It does not (and must not) matter whether you draw the 2-chloropentane with the substituted carbon to the right or to the left. Both ways are *identical.* Usually, you will chose an orientation that is consistent with further or earlier steps of your synthesis, but if you only have one one reaction that point is moot. (It matters a lot more in total synthesis, where it helps to draw reactands in a way that show their conformation in the final molecule.) Furthermore, there is a IUPAC style guide out there somewhere, which probably says one of the two ways is to be preferred if no other reasons speak for the other … but that’s more relevant for journal publications, not for practising or for exam answers.

So just for total consistency’s sake: Everything you did was correct; just remember that molecules can be drawn with different orientations, and learn to turn them around before your inner eye.

Comment: I think I'm rather shaky in my understanding and so am totally relying on the textbook solutions to verify my understanding of the material, but now I feel a little more confident about being able to present the information in a different manner. Thank you for your thorough explanation, and clear diagrams!